# npm install bcrypt on Windows Server 2012

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-server-2012, bcrypt, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm getting this error when trying to install my node modules for my node server.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK,
2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or
3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.
[C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PearsonRealty-   API\node_modules\bcrypt\build\binding.sln]
```

I've tried to install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, but it just exits out and never runs. I can't install Microsoft Visual Studio since I'm on an AWS EC2 instance and I wouldn't have enough space for it. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to install either VCExpress (preferrably at least 2015) *or* you can try the experimental [VC Build Tools solution](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/802) which is a smaller install than full-blown VCExpress. Otherwise, if you have one, you can try building on a local Windows machine first and then uploading the compiled addon directory to AWS.